# NoSql - entity holds an owner ID field vs owner holds list of child ID's

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, data-modeling, erd

I am currently exploring MongoDB.

I built a notes web app and for now the DB has 2 collections: `notes` and `users`.

The user can create, read and update his notes.

I want to create a page called `/my-notes` that will display all the notes that belong to the connected user.

My question is:

Should the notes model has an `ownerId` field or the opposite - the user model will have a field of `noteIds` of type list.

Points I found relevant for the decision making:

**`noteIds` approach:**

- There is no need to query the notes that hold the desired `ownerId` (say we have a lot of notes then we will need indexes and search accross the whole notes collection). We just need to find the user by user ID and then get all the notes by their IDs.
- In this case there are 2 calls to DB.
- The data is ordered by the order of insertion to the `notesIds` field in the document.

**`ownerId` approach:**

- We do need to find the notes by their `ownerId` field across the notes collection which might be more computer "intensive".
- We can paginate / sort the data as we want - more control over the data.

Are there any more points you can think of?

As I can conclude this is a question of whether you want less computer intensive DB calls vs more control over the data.

What are the "best practices"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A similar use case is explained in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/). If there is no limit on number of notes a user can have, it might be better to store a `userId` reference field in notes  document.

As you've figured out already, pagination would be easier in the second approach. Also when updating notes, you can simply `updateOne({ _id: "note_id", userId: 1 })` instead of checking user's document if the note actually belong to the user.